# TFS - opening task queries in MS project

Tags: tfs, ms-project

Using TFS 2010 and project 2007,  I am created several work items in TFS, some nested.  I open the task query in TFS and then choose the option to open the query in project.  MS project fires up and lists the work item ID, Title, Duration, Start, Finish, PRedecessors and resource names, and I would expect.   If I make changes in project and republish, all my changes are reflected in TFS.  Awesome!

From a project management perspective, the business in interested in % complete.  I know that MS project can normally track that value, so I insert the column in project, fill in some values and re-publish.  I can't see those values anywhere in TFS.  The completed work and remaining work columns in TFS represent hours, not percentages and do not correlate to % completed in MS project.  TFS does appear to be storing % complete somewhere, because when I publish the values in Project, close it, then requery from project, the values seem to be retained.  How can I view them from TFS?

Comment: In MSProject `% complete` is different than `% Work Complete`. `% Work Complete` should correspond to 1 - (  Work Remaining / total Work ) (= Actual Work / Total Work).  `% Complete` refers to how far along between the start date and the scheduled end date of the task you are. 'fraid I can't answer for the TFS side, though.

Comment: Why the downvote, this is a valid question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the integration between TFS and MS Project, there is a mapping file that indicates which fields are mapped. The % complete is not one of them. If you have added that field to your work item, you can [add that mapping yourself](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404684.aspx).